# Length of byte[] array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

```
String str = "123456789";
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
```

I want to make the following loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length(); j++) {
  b = bytes[j];
}
```

`b` will store each byte of my array, but I can't seem to get the length of the array correctly.

```
Error:cannot find symbol
Problem solved:  bytes.length instead of  bytes.length()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to get the length of the array correctly"?

Comment: Why not? What error do you get?

Comment: Netbeans shows an error 'cannot find symbol'.

Comment: Why do you think that is the case? Did you get an error? (You should use `bytes.length` instead of `bytes.length()`.)

Comment: -1 for not including the exact compiler error message.

Comment: Sorry, fairly new to stack.

Comment: Your should accept one of the answers,thats how SO works

Comment: It asks me to wait 10 minutes before doing that.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use `bytes.length` without the `()`

Answer (score 10):

See the [JLS - 10.7. Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> The `public final field length`, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. length may be positive or zero.

`length` is a *property*, not a method. You should write:

```
bytes.length
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the length of an array, use `length`. For example:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3};
int length = arr.length;
```

In order to get the length of a string, use `length()`. For example:

```
String str = "123";
int length = str.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not `bytes.length()`, its `bytes.length`

Answer (score 0):

getBytes() Encodes the String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

Try to print the bytes you will see the encoded values which may differ in length compare to original string.

Answer (score 0):

I second Sabuj's comment. It should be `bytes.length`